# PowerShell prompt for specific input then continue script

Tags: powershell

I'm stuck with this powershell script.

The script does the following:
When user presses y: 1.bat opens and runs for 3 second then closes.
Then the script asks the user if they want to run the 1.bat again, or when they press q the script NEEDS to continue, but the script ends

```
#Asks to start Password reset again if it fails
while($true) {
$readHostValue = Read-Host -Prompt "If Password reset fails enter y or q to continue install"

switch ($readHostValue) {
    'y' { Start-Process C:\Users\deniz\Desktop\1.bat -Verb RunAs }
    'q' { return # Ending password reset and continue script
        }
        Default { write-host "Invalid input y or n!" }
        }
    }
```

The script stops here, but needs to continue with the following:

```
#progress indicators/write-progress
Write-Progress -Activity "AfterLoader" -Status "Installing" -PercentComplete 10
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Rav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76221808/45375) points out, [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) in the context of a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement's action block exits the enclosing *function or script*.

By contrast, [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break) and - situationally<sup>[1]</sup> - [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Continue) exit the `switch` statement only, which means that your indefinite loop (`while ($true) { ... }`) continues, unless you take additional action.

In this case you can take advantage of a rarely seen variant of the `break` statement, namely one that can target a *labeled statement* to break out of:

```bash
# Note the self-chosen "menu:" label
:menu while ($true) {

  $readHostValue = Read-Host -Prompt 'If Password reset fails enter y or q to continue install'
  
  switch ($readHostValue) {
    'y'     { "running things..." }
    'q'     { break menu } # Break out of "menu:" labeled while loop.
    default { Write-Host 'Invalid input y or q!' }
  }

}

'continuing...'
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a Boolean variable to determine when to exit the `while` loop:

```bash
$continue = $true
while ($continue) {

  $readHostValue = Read-Host -Prompt 'If Password reset fails enter y or q to continue install'
  
  switch ($readHostValue) {
    'y'     { "running things..." }
    'q'     { 
       $continue = $false # signal that the while loop should exit
       break              # break out of the switch statement
    } 
    default { Write-Host 'Invalid input y or q!' }
  }

}

'continuing...'
```

---

<sup>[1] With *array*-valued `switch` input, `continue` proceeds to the *next element*. If the input is a single object or a single-element array `continue` has the same effect as `break`, i.e. it exits the statement.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement exit the entire script, not just the loop. That’s why your script stops there and does not execute the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but when I change return to continue, it still doesn't continue the script.